# Input limitando tipo de arquivo

Tags: html, formulário

Meu formulário tem um campo input file, e gostaria de limitar o tipo de arquivo a selecionar somente imagens e pdf.

```
<form>
<input type='file' required>
<input type='submit' name='Enviar'>
</form>
```

Estou tratando o tipo de arquivo no back-end, mas gostaria de limitar o tipo de arquivo a ser selecionado no front-end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta usar o `accept`:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Para determinar o tipo, precisa conhecer um pouco sobre Mime-Types. No exemplo acima, qualquer imagem serve.

Poderia ter usado `image/jpeg`, por exemplo, se quisesse restringir mais.

Conforme respondido pelo @DVD, no seu caso a sintaxe é essa:

```
<input type='file' required accept="image/*, application/pdf">
```

Separando por vírgula os tipos desejados.

Exemplos básicos:

```
text/plain
text/html
image/jpeg
image/png
audio/mpeg
audio/ogg
audio/*
video/mp4
application/octet-stream
```

Saiba mais sobre os Mime-Types aqui:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Basico_sobre_HTTP/MIME_types

Comment: Redondo, valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: @DVD eu acho válido restaurar a sua.

Answer (score 0):

Para aceitar imagens e PDF, você pode incluir no atributo [`accept`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) os dois mime-types separados por vírgula:

```
accept="image/*, application/pdf"
```

Então seu `input` ficaria assim:

```
<input type='file' required accept="image/*, application/pdf">
```

**Teste:**

```html
<form>
<input type='file' required accept="image/*, application/pdf">
<input type='submit' name='Enviar'>
</form>
```

Comment: vc quer que eu remova a minha resposta e vc corrige a sua? Posso fazer isso como sinal de consideração.

Comment: Não precisa não. Foi só uma observação pra deixar claro que eu noto isso, já removi. Inclusive, a sua está mais completa, então não vou criar caso. Aliás, se derem negativo, tenha certeza que nao sou eu (sério, eu fico P da vida com sacanagem, mas negativo em coisa boa nao é comigo)